# Read xml inside POM in Maven

Tags: maven

I want to read the below XML file using POM. and I want to run the POM based on the inputs given in POM.

```xml
<packging operation-mode="" server="" java-compiler-version="">
    <operation-layer name="framework">
        <operation-module name="framework" exclude-installation-mode="" exclude-server=""></operation-module>
        <operation-module name="admin" exclude-installation-mode="" exclude-server=""></operation-module>
        <operation-module name="tpe" exclude-installation-mode="" exclude-server=""></operation-module>
        <operation-module name="sample" exclude-installation-mode="" exclude-server=""></operation-module>
    </operation-layer>
    <operation-layer name="function">
        <operation-module name="function" exclude-installation-mode="" exclude-server=""></operation-module>
    </operation-layer>
    <operation-layer name="product">
        <operation-module name="product" exclude-installation-mode="" exclude-server=""></operation-module>
    </operation-layer>
    <operation-layer name="solution">
        <operation-module name="solution" exclude-installation-mode="" exclude-server=""></operation-module>
    </operation-layer>
</packging>
```

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do here. Why do you mean by "run the POM based on the inputs given in POM."?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ANT+xmltask in your pom at phase validate for example.